# How to make a pivot table from this data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like

```
data = {
    "Person": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Month": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "Value 1": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "Value 2": [10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want it to look like:

```
  Person   Value    Month 1  Month 2  Month 3  
0      A   1        5        6       7         
0      A   2        10       11      12        
0      B   1        8        9       10       
0      B   2        13       5       4        
...
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you get the `value` column in the output ?

Comment: I am not sure. That's why this is tricky. This certainly isn't my desired format haha. You are right: There are two different value columns, so I am not sure how I would do that.

Comment: you should know what are you aiming for. Else we will just guess and there would be followups which no one wants

Comment: I know what I am aiming for -- it is in the question. I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: In the body of question, I posted what the desired output is from the business end. When I said "I am not sure" I meant I am not sure how to get said output.

Comment: can you also post the full output desired according to the input? the `...` doesnt help

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind your pivoting?

Comment: I was asked to convert some tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, can `pivot_table`+`unstack`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='Month', index='Person')\
  .unstack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename(columns={'level_0': 'Value'})\
  .pivot_table(columns='Month', index=['Person', 'Value'])
```

Outputs

```
        Month          1       2        3       5       6
Person  Value                   
A       Value   1      5.0      6.0     7.0     NaN     NaN
        Value   2      10.0     11.0    12.0    NaN     NaN
B       Value   1      NaN      NaN     NaN     8.5     10.0
        Value   2      NaN      NaN     NaN     9.0     4.0
```

Comment: I like the logic here. :) +1

Comment: Yess! Thank you. As a bonus, is there anyway to add like a "YTD" column? So after the 6 there is another column that says "total" that is the result of summing the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `melt`

```
df1=df.melt(['Person','Month'])\
.pivot_table(index=['Person','variable'], columns=['Month'])
df1.index.rename(['Person','Value'], inplace=True)
df1.columns=df1.columns.droplevel()

        Month   1   2   3   5   6
Person  Value                   
A   Value 1     5.0 6.0 7.0 NaN NaN
    Value 2     10.0 11.0 12.0 NaN NaN
B   Value 1     NaN NaN NaN 8.5 10.0
    Value 2     NaN NaN NaN 9.0 4.0
```